# how to send notification to seller when payment is received

Tags: 7, ubercart, tokens

I want the system to send an email notification
to the author of the product when the payment
is received on their product. I have tried to run
the module mp_tokens this scenario but I do not
find the token [order-seller-email] there. please
help how to create a token for this issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming author of product is also seller, You can do this with a rule using loop and author:mail. Try importing this rule and see how it works

```
{ "rules_e_mail_seller_checkout_notification" : {
"LABEL" : "E-mail seller checkout notification",
"PLUGIN" : "reaction rule",
"REQUIRES" : [ "rules", "uc_cart" ],
"ON" : [ "uc_checkout_complete" ],
"DO" : [
  { "LOOP" : {
      "USING" : { "list" : [ "order:products" ] },
      "ITEM" : { "list_item" : "Current list item" },
      "DO" : [
        { "mail" : {
            "to" : "[list-item:node:author:mail]\u000D\u000A",
            "subject" : "OrderID: [list-item:order-id] Product: [list-item:title]",
            "message" : "Order: [list-item:order-id]\u000D\u000ANid: [list-item:nid]\u000D\u000ATitle: [list-item:title]\u000D\u000AQty: [list-item:qty]\u000D\u000APrice: [list-item:cost]\u000D\u000ASeller: [list-item:node:author]",
            "language" : [ "" ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
]
```

}
}

source - https://www.drupal.org/node/1830962

Answer (score 1):

One option is to use [Ubercart Rules](https://drupal.org/project/uc_rules) to add integration with Rules, and then [configure a reaction rule](https://drupal.org/node/1581680) to send an e-mail when payment completes.

Comment: I use drupal7 and I have tried rules, but I do not
find [author email product] or [node: author:
mail] as a token there

Answer (score 1):

You could use rules for this, Check this
http://www.drupalcommerce.org/user-guide/checkout-completion-rules

Comment: thanks for the reply, but I need this in Ubercart
+ Ubercart marketplace.